# How do I get correct encoding from my Postgre table when using st_read from the sf package in R

Tags: r, postgresql, r-sf

I want to read a table from my Postgre database (default encoding UTF8) and since it actually is a PostGIS table I am using the st package with st_read.

```
test_sf <- st_read(con, stringAsFactor = FALSE, layer = "test_df")
```

Running the command returns a message "type is 146", where I coulnd't find an explanation for the code. According to ISO there is no geometry type of code 146, but that's another story.

Looking at the data read into test_sf I can see that the font-encoding goes wrong. I have strings with letters such as 'ø' etc. The particular 'ø' is shown in RStudio as 'Ã¸'. Trying to solve that I was looking at the encoding of the particular column in the dataframe:

```
Encoding(test_sf[["status"]])
```

but the result shows only *unknown*. Altering the encoding `Encoding(test_sf[["status"]]) <- "latin1"` does show an encoding of *latin1* for all the strings with special characters, but all those where there are no special characters stay with an encoding of *unknown*. Even worst, a `View(test_sf)` is still showing the 'Ã¸' instead of an 'ø'.

When I look at the database table with DBeaver the font-encoding is correct. Reading the data in Python, the font-encoding is correct. Since I want to show the data in a plot in Shiny I want to use R.

How can I get a correct font-encoding of my data?

Answer (score 0):

I just see your question because I recently faced the same problem. So I write this function that allow to convert the character columns (because this was the incorrect columns in my case) in the encoding that you choose. In my case, I use UTF-8 but you can change it.

```
readable = function(df){
  x = sapply(df, class)
  if (class(df)[1] == "sf") { #if it's a sf object
    lst = list()
    for (i in names(x)) {
      if (x[i] == "character") { #just works with the columns with the character type
        lst[[i]] = (df[i])[1][[1]]
        Encoding(lst[[i]]) = "UTF-8"
        df[i] = lst[[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  else{ #if it's a data.frame
    for (i in names(x)) {
      if (x[i] == "character") {
        Encoding(df[, i]) = "UTF-8"
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

After you just have to make
`test_sf = readable(test_sf )` to convert the encoding